# Intellij IDEA: can not navigate from compiler error to source

Tags: intellij-idea

I get this annoying bug after upgrading Intellij IDEA from version 2019.1
to version 2019.2.1 or later

When compiling my code using the IDEA maven build tool, I now can't manage to navigate to the source file containing the error (from clicking at one of the errors out of the list of found errors listed on the side).

**Update:** a bug was submitted 2 days ago at jetbrains support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220999

> When I run maven compile from the the maven window, I expect my
>   compilation errors to be in the run window with hyperlinks that take
>   to the compilation error in the source file.  Since upgrade to version
>   2019.2 I can't get this functionality anymore.  The screen shot below is where I just reproduced the error and you can see there are no
>   hyperlinks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve:

edit the file: `~/.IdeaIC2019.2/config/options/other.xml`

change these stored values:

```
<property name="build.toolwindow.Build Output.selection.state" value="consoleView" />
<property name="build.toolwindow.Sync.selection.state" value="consoleView" />
<property name="build.toolwindow.run.selection.state" value="consoleView" />
```

to be:

```
<property name="build.toolwindow.Build Output.selection.state" value="com.intellij.build.BuildTreeConsoleView" />
<property name="build.toolwindow.Sync.selection.state" value="com.intellij.build.BuildTreeConsoleView" />
<property name="build.toolwindow.run.selection.state" value="com.intellij.build.BuildTreeConsoleView" />
```

save&restart Intellij